# How to perform get operation given generic data type on another object in Java?

Tags: java

We are trying to achieve below -

```
randomMethod(CustomClassType someClass, <classType>){
       return someClass.get<classType>();

}
```

```
CustomClassType {
      <T1> classType1;
      <T2> classType2;
}
```

I am not sure if this can be done in Java. Any help is appreciated.

Currently, we have different methods(random methods) which are doing this but we just want single method that could take generic class type and perform get operation on it.

Also for the sake of example I have just returning simple value but in real we have some work in that randomMethod but only difference being get operation for different class.

Any help us appreciated.

Comment: There _isn't_ really a great way do to this.  You could take a `Class` argument, and maybe manually reflect, assuming `CustomClassType` is not itself generic...

Comment: @LouisWasserman can you elaborate?